# How To Submit Two Forms With One Button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Please I have these two forms below. The first is the form that submit it's data to my database after my customer buys my product and were redirected to the registration page where the form is, while the second form is the form that submit it's data to my getresponse autoresponder campaign.

Now only the first form is what I wanted to be visible, I don't want the second form to be visible and I want to use one button to submit the two forms at one time, please how will I do that?

Thanks!

```
<!--====================================================================
Form that submit to my database and register my customers after purchase
======================================================================-->

<form class="form-horizontal templatemo-contact-form-1" role="form" action="sold.php" method="post">
        
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your First Name Here..." name="fname" required><br>
    <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name Here..." required><br>
    <input type="email" name="email"  class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Here..." required><br>
    <input type="text" name="phone"  class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number Here..." required><br>
    <input type="password" name="pword"  class="form-control" id="website" placeholder="Enter Your Password Here..." required><br>
    <input type="password" name="cpword"  class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Re-enter Your Password Here..." required><br>
    <input type="text" name="addrss"  class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Address Here..." required><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
</form>




<!--======================================================
Form that submit to my getresponse autoresponder campaign
========================================================-->
<form action="https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.html" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
 
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Enter your name here..." type=text style="width: 100%">      
    <input type="text" name="email" value="Enter your email here..." type=text style="width: 100%">
    <!-- Get the token at: https://app.getresponse.com/campaign_list.html -->
    <input type="hidden" name="campaign_token" value="ljqOk" />
    <!-- Thank you page (optional) -->
    <input type="hidden" name="thankyou_url" value="https://www.moneycreativesecret.com/spages/smf-sp1/"/>
    <!-- Add subscriber to the follow-up sequence with a specified day (optional) -->
    <input type="hidden" name="start_day" value="0" />
    <!-- Forward form data to your page (optional) -->
    <input type="hidden" name="forward_data" value="post" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="100% Free Access" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
</form>
```

Comment: You can't submit two forms simultaneously unless you use AJAX

Comment: You can't. Only one form request can be made

Comment: It'd make more sense to send a request to getresponse from your `sold.php` server-side code then

Comment: *"The first is the form that submit it's data to my database after my customer buys my product"* - Seeing that this is business/money related, consider hiring a developer. Did you not research this and tried something? We're always happy to help, just not to do it for you. (*without prejudice*).

Comment: @Oliver Afabuike You can place all the inputs in the second form inside the first form and hidden them via `<input type="hidden">`. The inputs will not be visible and they will be sent when the form is submitted. MDN has an example of this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden

Comment: From there, you can add an `onSubmit` handler to the form and execute 2 ajax calls in parallel(assuming that both calls are independent of each other and you don't have to wait for one of the calls to finish). One to https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.html and one to wherever `sold.php` makes a request to. Hope that helps.

Comment: @ ADyson Ok Thanks, But there must be a way out!

Comment: @ CherryDT Thanks very much, I think u have the same thing I have in mind, I will try that and share result!

Comment: @ Luis Averhoff, You are great, I will try that only that I do not know much about Ajax but I will check it out!